# Работа с памятью в С++(Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, global-variables

Здравствуйте, пишу приложение на С++(Qt), которое работает с БД и в процессе всей моей работы у меня возник вопрос в каких ситуациях, когда и где выделять память под переменную? К примеру у меня есть форма, которая использует один общий запрос, я определяю переменную под этот запрос и вопрос в том где ее лучше выделить в стэке или в куче?

```
namespace Ui {
class ClassesForm;
}

class ClassesForm : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
    ...
    private:
    ...
    QString selectedClass; // или QString *selectedClass и в конструкторе 
    //выделить память под нее?
};
```

И к примеру есть функция в которой используется другой запрос, который не используется нигде кроме этой формы, в этом случае, где ее выделять?

```
void ClassesForm::changeDescriptionOfClass()
{
    QString query; //Или выделять память?
    ...
}
```

Хотелось бы получить внятный ответ, не только об этих примерах, но и в целом внятный вопрос когда, что и где лучше использовать...

Comment: Здесь точно нет смысла выделять динамически память.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет смысла динамически выделять память, только если для вас это не критичный параметр. Вот здесь хорошо всё расписано про динамическое выделение памяти - https://habrahabr.ru/company/aligntechnology/blog/283352/

*Основная мысль: старайтесь убрать вызовы new и delete из клиентского кода. Они нужны только в исключительных случаях, и эти случаи требуют исключительного внимания. Например, это создание собственного контейнера или менеджера памяти.*